# Fullcalendar dayRender does not define cell property

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, undefined, fullcalendar-4

I use the [fullcalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io) plugin and I want to add some extra html in every cell of the calendar, but in console I receive the following error:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of undefined
> at Calendar.dayRender (mycode.js?v=1.x:31)
> at Calendar.publiclyTrigger (main.js?v=1.x:6949)
> at DayGrid.DateComponent.publiclyTrigger (main.js?v=1.x:4008)
> at DayGrid._renderCells (main.js?v=1.x:796)
> at DayGrid.res [as renderCells] (main.js?v=1.x:3189)
> at DayGrid.render (main.js?v=1.x:740)
> at DayGrid.Component.receiveProps (main.js?v=1.x:3887)
> at SimpleDayGrid.render (main.js?v=1.x:1520)
> at SimpleDayGrid.Component.receiveProps (main.js?v=1.x:3887)
> at DayGridView.render (main.js?v=1.x:1586)
> ```

var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

```
      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
        defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',//'timeGridWeek',
        header: {
          left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
        },
        defaultDate: '2019-07-12',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        dayRender: function(date, element) {
          element.append("<input type=\"checkbox\">AM<br>");
        }

      });
```

I think for some reason the dayRender does not define the elemement variable. Why this may happening?

Comment: Have you tried checking the dayRender documentation? See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayRender . Can you see if there is any `element` parameter defined in the docs? No. Everything is provided under one parameter, as sub-properties within it.

Comment: P.S. Your dayRender code would have been correct for version 3: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/dayRender - have you been using version 3 previously, perhaps? N.B. It's also worth noting that references to HTML elements are provided as native DOM elements in v4, not as jQuery objects (as per the [upgrade guide](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3)) so make sure you use appropriate function calls on your elements as well.

Comment: Conclusion: always read the documentation for the correct version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Full Calendar v 4.0, as suggested by ADyson, use dayRender as follow:

```
dayRender: function (dayRenderInfo) {
   dayRenderInfo.el.innerHTML = "<input type=\"checkbox\">AM<br>";
}
```